# SAP HANA Input Parameter Mapping

Tags: hana

I am trying to map input parameters between HANA Calculation Views.

When I use the "Manage Mappings" menu in the first Calculation View to map its input parameter to the one of the second Calculation View (which is a data source in the first view), there are no Input Parameters proposed for the mapping.

What might be the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Hana ur using?
if it is sp08 and below, then check if any of the underlying views has any filters like null of not null. Remove such filters and they try to map the input parameters